# Request in PhantomJS and NodeJS not working in specific webpage

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to get information from a site using Phantom on NodeJS. My code is as follows:

```
const phantom = require('phantom');

const instance = await phantom.create(['--local-url-access=false', '--ssl-protocol=any']);
const page = await instance.createPage();

await page.on('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
    console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
});

page.open('https://www.google.com/').then(async (status) => {
    await instance.exit();

    resolve(null);
}).catch((err) => {
    reject(err);
});
```

It works without problems, but when I put the url `https://reclameaqui.com.br` does not load the content

Answer (score -1):

When I am using this code in an API it is working fine.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const phantom = require("phantom");

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", async function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("index", { title: "Express" });

  const instance = await phantom.create([
    "--local-url-access=false",
    "--ssl-protocol=any"
  ]);
  const page = await instance.createPage();

  await page.on("onResourceRequested", function(requestData) {
    // console.info("Requesting", requestData.url);
    console.log(requestData);
  });

  page
    .open("https://reclameaqui.com.br/")
    .then(async status => {
      await instance.exit();

      resolve(null);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in this case the code not return status response data, only request. If you try `.then(async status => { console.log(status); });` this not working